# Can I use the insert function to add elements into a vector of vectors?

Tags: c++, vector

I would like to know, can I use insert keyword to add elements into `vector` of `vector`?
For example, I have a `vector` `vector<int> temp1;` for this `vector`, elements add within the inner `for` loop. at the end of out `for` loop, I need to add the elements to `temp1`;

```
vector<vector<int> >temp1;
for (int a;a<size(),a++){//...
  vector<int> temp2;
  for (int b=0;b<closer_points;b++){

       // some steps here...

       vector<int> pt_no=mydata.Find_End_point(my_list,s1,s2);
       temp2=pt_no;
       }
  temp1[a].insert(temp1[a].end(),temp2.begin(),temp2.end());
  }
```

then, i tried to print `temp1`, line by line as elements of `temp2` are appearing in a one line.

```
for(int i=0;i<temp1.size();i++){
    for(int j=0;j<temp1[i].size();j++){
        cout<<" t2 "<<temp1[i][j];
        }
    cout<<endl;
    }
```

but, this doesnt work. can anyone rectify this, plz...

Comment: What doesn't work? What is the error message?

Comment: if you want us to look at your code can you format it correctly please?

Comment: @larry - i am sorry not to inserting my whole code. it is quite long, but i updated few more, the place where i get temp2. (i am really sorry, if i make any inconveniences or confusion due to this)

Comment: @g_niro: You need to indent code 4 spaces to enable syntax highlighting and block-mode here on SO. Best is, just highlight your code and press ctrl+K or those `{}` at the top of the question. :)

Comment: Pedantic note: `insert` is not a *keyword* in C++. It is a *method* on `std::vector`. Also, please consider using the space bar occasionally when typing lines of code. It makes it a lot more readable. As do variable names that don't begin with `temp`, but rather represent the data they contain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Question:

> temp1[a].insert(temp1[a].end(),temp2.begin(),temp2.end());

#### Reinstated prior answer:

To append a range of values to an existing vector:

```
std::copy(temp2.begin(),temp2.end(), std::back_inserter(temp1));
```

To append the range *as a new vector* to an existing vector_of_vectors:

```
vector<vector<int> > vecvec;
vector<int> toappend;

// some steps :)
vecvec.push_back(toappend);

// or
vecvec.push_back(vector<int>(toappend.begin(), toappend.end());
```

include `<iterator>` and `<algorithm>` if you haven't got them already

### Update

> if i say like this; i have set of points. i want to group these points into vectors and then to put those into another vector at the end. so, i gues my final output is vector of vector. for example, final result should look like ((1,3),(4,6,9,8,21),(5,7,12),..).

Ok, here goes:

```
// (
std::vector<std::vector<int> > vecvec;
// (1,3)
{
    std::vector<int> vec;
    vec.push_back(1);
    vec.push_back(3);

    vecvec.push_back(vec);
}
// (4,6,9,8,21)
{
    std::vector<int> vec;
    vec.push_back(4);
    vec.push_back(6);
    vec.push_back(9);
    vec.push_back(8);
    vec.push_back(21);

    vecvec.push_back(vec);
}
// (5,7,12)
{
    std::vector<int> vec;
    vec.push_back(5);
    vec.push_back(7);
    vec.push_back(12);

    vecvec.push_back(vec);
}
// )
//  ....
... // (use vecvec)
```

Comment: @sehe, i think i couldn't tell what i need exactly, i need to add elements of temp2 to the temp1 as a vector of vector. so, my question is, can i use insert fuction for this purpose and how. i tried with above way, but couldnt get the ansewer.

Comment: Allthough it isn't clear to me what the code should do, I have added suggestions (perhaps minimize the sample into working code except for the problem line?)

Comment: @ sehe; thank you very much for further comments. but, still i cannot sove the problem. if i say like this; i have set of points. i want to group these points into vectors and then to put those into another vector at the end. 
so, i gues my final output is vector of vector.
for example, final result should look like ((1,3),(4,6,9,8,21),(5,7,12),..). so, give me some more hints.

Comment: g_niro: `so give me some more hints` (excuse me?); `'i have set of points'` - how would you represent such a point?

Comment: @ sehe-> thank you, but your previous explanation i.e. total.push_back(vector<double> (test.begin(), test.end()));  was correct. thanks for that. (i had some other error thats why i was late to tell this) those values were just and example to explain what i need. so, it is good to make available your previous code parts too. thanks

Comment: @g_niro: fixed the answer to restore the deleted bits

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `temp1.push_back(temp2);`